# Translation of “with that”

Tags: prépositions

I swear I saw a thread here (or somewhere) recently that translated the phrase “with that” in the following kind of context:

-She caused a scene, and with that, she made her exit.

I’m not worried about translating that sentence specifically (it’s more of an example so you know what I mean) but I can’t for the life of me find the phrase I saw as the French equivalent. I googled it and came up with “avec ça” but that’s not the phrase I originally saw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the possible translations that come to my mind would be :

- Elle fit une scène, **puis** s'en alla
- Elle fit une scène, **et sur ce** s'en alla
- Elle fit une scène, **et avec ça** s'en alla
- Elle fit une scène, **et aussitôt après** s'en alla
- Elle fit une scène, **et là-dessus** s'en alla

Comment: It turns out là-dessus is what I was looking for! Thank you for all the possible translations.

Answer (score 2):

Literary:

> Elle a fait un esclandre et sur ce, s'en est allée.

Colloquial:

> Elle a piqué sa crise et aussi sec, s'est cassée.

Answer (score 1):

In this context "with that" is translated as "sur ce". That's probably what you are trying to get back at.

- Elle a fait une scène et **sur ce** elle a fait sa sortie.

Comment: Are “ce” and “elle” not elided in this case?

Comment: @tssmith2425 No, there is never an elision for this locution.

Comment: Thank you so much. You always provide such detailed responses and I always appreciate it.

Comment: @tssmith2425 You welcome, glad my answers can help!